# Virtual function not called in class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

In the `main()` function below, `d` is a base class pointer (of type `A`) which points to a derived class (of type `B`). Yet when the member function `f(int)` is called on this pointer, i.e. `d->f(1)`, the compiler calls the non-virtual function in the base class A (labelled `#2`), i.e.

```
void f(int n) const { std::cout << n; }
```

Why? I was expecting that since there is also a virtual function in the base class `A`

```
virtual void f(int n) { std::cout << n; }
```

one of the two functions `f(int)` in the derived class `B` would be called. Where am I going wrong?

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}

public:
    virtual void f(int n) { std::cout << n; }  // #1
    virtual ~A() { }

    void f(int n) const { std::cout << n; } // #2 this function is called when d->f(1) is executed in main()
};

class B
    : public A
{
public:
    void f(int n) { std::cout << n; }  // #3

    void f(int n) const { std::cout << n; }  // #4
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    const A* d = &b;

    d->f(1); // this calls function #2 above - why?

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `d` is a `const A*` so operations cannot be done on `d` that logically change the object it points to. So `d->f(1)` needs to call the `const` version of `f()`, as only that function promises not to change the object pointed to by `d`.   Remove the `const` versions of `f()` from class `A`, and the result will be a diagnostic from your compiler due to attempt to call a `non-`const` member function of a `const` object. The facts that `b` is not `const` or that one version of `f()` is `virtual` are irrelevant -  the `const` qualifier when declaring `d` means that `d` cannot be used to change `b`.

Comment: @Peter - oh goodness... in my rush to understand the code I completely overlooked the obvious fact that d is const. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: I've taken the liberty of labelling all the versions of `f` so that they are easier to refer to. If this is acceptable, I'll update my answer as well to use those labels.

Comment: @cigien - good idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` is a pointer to a const `A`. This means any call to a member function will call the const-qualified overload if one exists. In your case, the const-qualified version of `f` in the base class (`#2`) is not `virtual`, so the fact that `d` is pointing to a `B` object doesn't matter. The base class const-qualified overload is the one that is chosen to be called.

If you make the const-qualified overload of `f` in the base class `virtual` then the const-qualified overload in the derived class (`#4`) will be chosen.

Similarly, if `d` is a pointer to a non-const `A`, then the non-const-qualified overload of `f` in the derived class (`#3`) will be called, since the overload in the base class (`#1`) is `virtual`.

Comment: @ cigien - thank you - as I mentioned to @Peter, my bad for overlooking this obvious fact that d is const.

Comment: @Marco Ah good, I'm glad you figured it out.